# Generating truly random numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Is it possible to create a truly random number in JavaScript?

I have tried here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stroogle_/vhndbnod/4/)

Javascript:

```
    // Mouse coordinates on click
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn1").click(function(e){
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
  });

});


// Timing mouse down
var pressed;
var duration;

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn1").on("mousedown", function(){
    pressed = +new Date();
  });
  $("#btn1").on("mouseup", function(){
    duration = +new Date() - pressed;
  });

});

// Time since last click
var loaded;
var onPush;
$(document).ready(function(){

  loaded = +new Date();
  $("#btn1").on("mousedown", function(){
    onPush = +new Date() - loaded;
    loaded = +new Date();
  });

});

// Extending process for pseudorandom number? or creating a truly random number?
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").on("click", function(){

    function rnum(min, max) {
      var a = Math.random();
      var ranMouseX = mouseX * a;
      var ranMouseY = mouseY * a;
      var ranDuration = duration * a;
      var ranOnPush = onPush * a;

      var combine = ((ranMouseX / ranOnPush) + (ranMouseY / ranDuration) % a);
      $("#p1").text(((combine - Math.floor(combine)) * (max-min) + min).toFixed(0))
    };
    var f = document.getElementById('min');
    var g = document.getElementById('max');
    rnum(parseInt(f.value), parseInt(g.value));
  });
});
```

But have I just extended the process for a pseudo-random number? or does this make a truly random number?

If it is still just a pseudo-random number how can I make a truly random number in JavaScript?

Comment: truly random numbers require a truly random source of noise, usually physical....Trying to make your own 'more' random numbers invariably leads to generating something less random! Random number generation is best left to the experts.

Comment: `Math.random()` is just fine, don't really understand what you're looking for. From that original random number, just perform some calculation/computation to get your own random numbers (with such as greater values, ...).

Comment: https://www.random.org/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: If you're really concerned about getting truly random numbers you can use random.org http interface, but in most cases Math.random() is just enough https://www.random.org/clients/http/

Comment: Beyond the emotional satisfaction of saying "truly random" -- what are you trying to accomplish? It is a fairly deep area. JavaScript's PRNG is adequate for most  purposes (though it does fall short of e.g. Python's). You could always implement your own version of e.g. the Mersenne Twister -- but do you really need it? This is interesting: https://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/12/theres-mathrandom-and-then-theres.html

Answer (score 3):

From default APIs, you'll be stuck with pseudo-random (truly random would require a physical interface).

However, the [`Crypto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto) interface does provide a *crypto-safe* random number generator : [`Crypto.getRandomValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues) which seeds have more entropy than the default `Math.random()` method.

```js
var array = new Uint32Array(10);
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: How can I use this to hex 64 characters of Hex Values?

Answer (score 1):

There is an API - [ANU Quantum Random Number Generator API](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/anu-quantum-random-number-generator) that you can use. From the description:

> The numbers are considered to be "truly random", because they are generated by measuring the quantum fluctuations of a vacuum